# Error While Connecting to Happy Fox API to extract customer data using Anypoint Studio?

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, api

I am trying to connect to a custom API for extracting customer data from chat API, I won't be able to connect to the API getting the below errors.

```
+ Initializing domain 'default'                            +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:33,036 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule artifact archive: file:/D:/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1.zip
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:33,290 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1'                +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:33,635 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1'       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
WARN  2018-02-24 11:10:34,496 [main] com.mulesoft.module.client.APIPlatformClientCoreExtension: Client ID or Client Secret were not provided. API Manager client is DISABLED for app testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:34,515 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:34,655 [main] org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Starting discovery of extensions
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:34,854 [main] org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Discovered 1 extensions
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:34,854 [main] org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager: Registering extension validation (version 3.8)
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:34,936 [main] org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Refreshing org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@4d2c4eaa: startup date [Sat Feb 24 11:10:34 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:36,646 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
ERROR 2018-02-24 11:10:36,762 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MuleDocumentLoader.java:91) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:192) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:58) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:165) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:254) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:76) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:279) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.8.4.jar:?]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 50 in XML document from URL [file:/D:/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1/api.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 50 in XML document from URL [file:/D:/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1/api.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Line 50 in XML document from URL [file:/D:/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1/api.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'.
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:112) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 50 in XML document from URL [file:/D:/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/testing-apikit-with-munit_1.4.1/api.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:192) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:102) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:54) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.3: '' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processOneAttribute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.<a href="https://asha24.com/blog/mulesoft-esb-tutorial">mule</a>.config.spring.MuleDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MuleDocumentLoader.java:91) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:192) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar:4.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104)     at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.4.jar:3.8.4]
    ... 13 more
INFO  2018-02-24 11:10:36,996 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher:
```

I've configured [Mulesoft](https://asha24.com/blog/mulesoft-esb-tutorial) following a tutorial, can this be the case something wrong with my Mulesoft studio version?

As I can't really find any product compatibility matrix. It would be great if anyone suggest some tips around it.

Comment: Could you please also show us your code (usage of the API)?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing not compatible value in line of 50 of your api.xml file.
share your configuration xml file for more details.